# AHK Script for making Control+v work in non-CMD terminals (Bash, Putty, WSL...)

Tags: bash, automation, autohotkey, putty, wsl-2

I want an AHK Script that remaps `Control+v` to send the Clipboard, as it is intended, in non-CMD terminals, like Bash and Putty.

Each terminal has a different command to paste the clipboard and it's always annoying to remmber which I should use in that moment. And the usual `Control+C` , `Control+V` causes some weird characters to appear (`^[[200~...~`), which then I need to delete manually.

---

I created the following script:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.

; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.

SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.

SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

#SingleInstance, Force  

SetKeyDelay -1

^v::

sendRaw,% clipboard

return
```

Which works 'fine', but have some small cavieats:

When I copy something that expect another char to come right after, such as ` ´ ^ ~, or chars that are expected in pairs, such as " ( [ {, it has a strange behaviour, instead of just pasting the unique char I copied. On the first case, I have to paste twice in oder to anything to appear and then remove one of the duplicated chars. On the second, when the apps expect closures, like VScode, Intellij, instead of printing just the char I copied, it prints the opening and the closing characters, which I then have to delete the later.

Comment: Try the [Text mode](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v2/lib/Send.htm#Text).

Comment: Text Mode did help, fixed the first problem almost completelly (for some reason, now the ahk is trigering Power  Toys `Control+control`, but that's manageble). Second issue persists, but I think this is more related on how the application perceives the input...

Answer (score 0):

As per [Relax](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3419297/relax) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77691938/ahk-script-for-making-controlv-work-in-non-cmd-terminals-bash-putty-wsl#comment136968482_77691938), `text mode` solved almost all use cases...

In the end I had to use `#IfWinActive`, because print screens wouldn't work with that implementation...

That's the final solution:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.
#SingleInstance, Force  
SetKeyDelay -1

#IfWinActive, ahk_exe mintty.exe 
^v::
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe cmd.exe
^v::
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe putty.exe
^v::
  send {Text}%clipboard% 
return
```

Comment: ps: I'm still searching for better solutions... :/

Answer (score 0):

In PuTTY, the insert hot key sequence is <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd>.

I think if it's possible to use AutoHotKey to intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, and have it send <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Insert</kbd> to the PuTTY window, that should make PuTTY do a paste from the clipboard.

This AHK Version 2 script works for me:

```
#HotIfWinActive("ahk_exe putty.exe")
^v::Send "+{Ins}"
return
```

When this is active, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in Putty performs a paste.

Those weird characters `^[[200~...~` are the Xterm mouse protocol. You get the same if you paste with the mouse button. It's a long escape sequence that contains the paste data. It requires the program on the other end to understand the protocol. Vim has support for it, for instance.

PuTTY is not always in this Xterm mouse mode. I find that it gets into that mode "by accident" somehow, and won't come out of it even when the correct escape sequence is issued for exiting the mode. It can be a nuisance.

I suspect that if Vim is in that Xterm mouse mode, you will get those funny characters no matter how you paste (such as with the above AHK script). That is to say, PuTTY's paste feature is doing that, and there is probably no way around it other than to turn off the Xterm mouse mode.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the Xterm explanation. It happens more ir git Bash... In putty I'm only able to paste with mouse right click. My code does work for them, as it doesn't 'paste' the content, it rewrites it... I need a somewhat holistic solution because I use many terminals everyday, from Pwsh to Linux based contianers in Putty... That's why I didn't want the `#IfWinActive` solution, but couldn't find another...

Comment: @ViníciusMatos I see; the SendText solution just dumps the clipboard contents into the window as if it were keystrokes.  Could that have some drawbacks? Does it work with international text? How about very large pastes?

Comment: Very large pastes take some extra time, when compared to the normal paste, but nothing major, max of 1 sec... The true draw back is that images and non-text would not be pasted, that's why I had to include the Win active...

Comment: @ViníciusMatos  I think it rather goes without saying that you don't want to globally hijack Ctrl-V and turn it into something that sends the clipboard text as a bunch of keystrokes to every kind of window and application! You break too many things.

Comment: I used AHK to make a global hotkey before, but with a very obscure key combination that no app uses for anything. It would bring to the foreground a certain VPN login dialog, put in my creds, and log in. I think I had it somehow so that the password would come from a dialog when the scripts starts (not hard coded into the file). I did all that because the free edition of the VPN client didn't allow saving of credentials and reconnect.

Comment: I guess you are right. I didn't experienced any major issues,  other than the image pasting, but it would be just a matter of time...

Comment: I have a second layer with F24 wrapping,  but for this use case I really wanted something seamless,  due to muscle memory... Although the solution been imperfect, with Win Active it has been working nice for me, no major hiccup!